# Problem when fading DIVs with Google Fonts embedded on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fade, google-font-api

I have several DIVs that embed Google Fonts and on click, these DIVs fade in and out to switch content. However with Google font installed, the font edges darken when faded in on Internet Explorer 7.

The page in question is: http://picco.sonikastudios.com/about-picco/management-team/

When clicking on the staff photos, it should switch the DIVs. on my IE7, once the fonts are faded in it gets blackened on the edges, similar to how PNGs do that.

I'm using jQuery in order to fade in & out.